# Alternate computation for variance derivation

Tags: statistics, expected-value, variance

How does the third line follow from the second in the following derivation?

$$
\sigma^2 = E[(X-\mu)^2] = E[X^2-2\mu X + \mu^2]
\\
= E(X^2)-2\mu E(X)+\mu^2
\\
= E(X^2)-\mu^2
$$

Comment: $E(X)=\mu$ and simplify.